# Finding the Max of Select Query

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am new developer for JPA and have a assignment to write the retrieve records from database using JPQL. Below is my Query. Basically I am trying to find the max of field1 from table Z.

```
SELECT X.Id,        
     MAX (
        NVL (
           (SELECT field1
              FROM table Z
             WHERE  X.Id = Z.id.Id),'')) field
FROM table1 X, table2 Y
WHERE X.Id = Y.Id
group by X.Id
```

While Executing this query I am getting the error as below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.AggregateNode 
 \-[AGGREGATE] AggregateNode: 'MAX'
\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
   +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'NVL' {originalText=NVL}
   \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
```

Please Advise. When I am running the query using normal sql, its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with **''** :

```
NVL (
       (SELECT field1
          FROM table Z
         WHERE  X.Id = Z.id.Id),'')
```

try something like this:

```
   NVL (
       (SELECT field1
          FROM table Z
         WHERE  X.Id = Z.id.Id),0)
```

Comment: I tried doing this, the error looks to be same. When I tried removing the SELECT Query from the MAX and do something like MAX(somefield), it is working fine. Do you think if there are issues with the Syntax? Please let me know

Comment: Does jpql supports such syntax to find max of subquery like select?

Comment: Let me know if JPQL do not support subquery in MAX. Advise if this is a spec constraint?

Comment: I'am sure that jpql allow subquery in max clausule. If you have not data type error, it means that there is nothing(no records) in MAX clausule so it wont work.

Comment: But since there is NVL, in this case it should return ZERO value..but it was still throwing the same error. I tried NVL with for ZERO as well

Comment: I've never use nvl function. Maybe try use something like coalesce instead? Or try this query: MAX(select 1 from table Z where X.Id=Z.id.Id) if it work you will be sure that problem is with NVL function, not with subquery.